# Chrome Extension that recognises Text Input and show's Pop Up

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, google-chrome-extension

Part of my Chrome Extension allows a user to enter a string into a textfield, check if any words entered match with items in an array.

If the user's string contains a named object in the array then I want it to be replaced with a link. All this works fine but the issue is that this has to be done with the chrome extension window.

How can I build it so it recognizes a user's input on a website, say Google Docs, and shows me a pop-up if that typed word matches an item in the array?

**Manifest.json**

```
{
  "name": "Extension",
  "description": "Extension Description",
  "version": "1.0",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "permissions": [
    "activeTab"
  ],
  "browser_action": {
    "default_popup": "index.html",
    "default_title": "Open the popup"
  },
  "icons": {
    "16": "logo192.png",
    "48": "logo192.png",
    "128": "logo192.png"
  },
}
```

**App.JS**

```
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import { Grid, Stack, TextField, Button,Container } from '@mui/material';

function App() {
  const [content, setContent] = useState('')
  const [internalLinks, setInternalLinks] = useState([
    {
      name: 'Sam',
      link: 'somewhere@gmail.com'
  },

  {
      name: 'Ash',
      link: 'something@gmail.com'
  }
  ])
  const generateContent = (content) => {
    if (internalLinks.some((v => content === v.name))) {
    }
    const final = internalLinks.reduce((a, b) => {
      return a.replaceAll(b.name, '<a href=' + b.link + '>' + b.name + '</a>');
    }, content);
    return final;
  };
  return (
    <Container >
      <Stack direction="column" alignItems="center" justifyContent="space-between" mb={5}>
        </Stack>
        <Stack direction="row" alignItems="start" justifyContent="start" mb={5}>
      <TextField 
          name="Content" placeholder="Content" multiline={true}
          value={content}
          rows={18}
          sx={{width: '100%'}}
          onChange={(e) => setContent(e.target.value)}
          />
    <div style={{maxWidth:"50%", paddingLeft:"10px"}} dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: generateContent(content)}}></div>
    </Stack>
    </Container>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: You can do that with a [content script](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/content_scripts/)

Answer (score 0):

Have a content script to identify contentEditable/textarea (you can use querySelector) and add eventListeners/observers to the element to get the content. If the text matches your requirement, send a message from the content script to the background script(service worker), upon receiving the message you can open your popup from the background.
Be familiar with content and background scripts. You can read about message passing [here](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/messaging/).

Comment: you can identify the editable and add listeners to it upon page load.

Comment: Okay I’ll give it a go